# ExifInterface_JNI: Raw image not detected error

Tags: android

When trying to get the ExifInterface I keep seeing a Raw image not detected error message.

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filepath); 
int rotation=exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: The fact that you are getting an error message about JNI suggests that you are using [the wrong `ExifInterface`, the one with the nasty security flaw](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/08/dealing-exifinterface-security-flaw.html). Please consider using [the one from the Android Support library](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/12/15/about-support-exifinterface.html) or [another implementation](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/31/tale-two-exifinterfaces.html). Beyond that, what is the value of `filepath`, and where did you get it from?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am getting it from a Uri but I know the filepath exists.  Where do I get a different version of the ExifInterface? I am using Android support-v4:25.3.0 though I am not sure if this is where the ExifInterface implementation is coming from (I am relatively new to android development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am getting it from a Uri but I know the filepath exists

Those statements are mutually contradictory. **A `Uri` is not a file**. *If* the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, *then and only then* can you get a filesystem path to the file, by means of `getPath()`. If the scheme is *anything else*, such as `content`, then you cannot get a filesystem path, because there is no requirement that there be a file. For example, a `Uri` of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930509/exifinterface-jni-raw-image-not-detected-error` does not mean that the Android device has a file at `/questions/42930509/exifinterface-jni-raw-image-not-detected-error`.

The `ExifInterface` from `com.android.support:exifinterface` (e.g., where the current latest version is 25.3.0) has [a constructor that takes an `InputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)). Create a `ContentResolver` (via `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`). Call `openInputStream()` on that `ContentResolver`, supplying the `Uri` (works for both `file` and `content` schemes). Pass that `InputStream` to the library's `ExifInterface` constructor. This simultaneously ensures that you do not cause security problems for your users *and* avoids having to worry about getting a filesystem path for the content that you wish to examine.

Comment: I am getting it from a Uri by calling getPath() and I have also created a file object and tested if the file exists which returns true.

Comment: We have a min SDK version of 19 so I am unable to use the ExifInterface(InputStream) constructor. Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: @JohnKane: "I am unable to use the ExifInterface(InputStream) constructor" -- yes, you are. You are confusing `android.media.ExifInterface` (the built-in one that **nobody should be using**) with `android.support.media.ExifInterface` (the one from the library, that I referenced in my answer). Add `compile 'com.support.android:exifinterface:25.3.0'` to your `dependencies` closure, alongside the `support-v4:25.3.0` dependency. Then, use `android.support.media.ExifInterface`.

Comment: Thank you, I added that line to the dependencies, however, I am still getting an orientation of 0 regardless of the orientation of the phone when I try to read in the Attribute: exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Comment: @JohnKane: Perhaps the image does not have an orientation tag. If it is a JPEG, download it from the device and examine it with appropriate tools (e.g., `exif` command in Linux) to see whether it has a tag. If it is not a JPEG, then there may not be any EXIF headers to work with.

Comment: I think this is something local to my machine. I have tried running code that gives exif data on someone elses machine and it still fails on mine...  It doesnt make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, apply the below example to your code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f); 
// where f of type File 
in = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
// context should refer to your context app
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(in);
// you'll need "exifInterface"
```

And don't forget to close your input stream

```
in.close();
```